# Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection while writing xlsx

Tags: r, xlsx

I am not a newbie in R, but during my last work session something weird occurred and I was not able to find any other answer here.

I am using an xlsx package. 
When I am writing my code in a script an error pops up in the console  `Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection`
and [new error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJSI0.png) appears on screen.

My code looks like this when it happens `read.xlsx(`

I double checked my working directory and also file with installed libraries. Everything seems ok. When I click OK, I can continue writing my code. Sometimes the error shows up more than once during one command.

It is bothering and annoying and I would like to know, what is happening.

Thank you for any thoughts

(I am not sure if that's relevant, but I am having other issues with read.xlsx function. Particulary with sheet uploading. It looks like it cannot read the name of sheet and uses only its index.

```
df <- read.xlsx("foo.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, encoding="UTF-8", 
stringsAsFactors = F) 

df <- read.xlsx("foo.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet 1", 
encoding="UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = F) 

Error in read.xlsx("foo.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet 1", : 
Cannot find the sheet you requested in the file! )
```

Comment: generally excel sheets are names as Sheet1 , you are making mistake with sheet names please have a look you are writing Sheet 1

Comment: not reproducible, but some things you could try:
- check path regarding special characters ; 
- clear workspace and restart RStudio session;
- delete `.Rhistory` and `.Rdata`files.

Comment: I know it is not reproducible. But how could I change it?
I cleared everything, tried restarting several times. Still doing the same. I am not aware of any change in my code, computer or RStudio.

Comment: I just saw that you try to open a `.xls`-file with function `read.xlsx` (or is this just a typo?). Maybe this is the problem and you should use the `openXL`-function.

Comment: Yes, it was just a mistake. I corrected it. But I will check th  `openXL`  function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Usually new Excel sheet are named *Sheet1*, *Sheet2*, ... 
not with the space between the word "Sheet" and the number. I think this might solve the problem.

Comment: "Sheet 1" name is just an example. I am getting data from somewhere else and their sheets have names with multiple words and spaces between them. 
So I am using the same names as in the excel.